# Java web start permission problems?

Tags: java, macos, permissions, java-web-start

[image: Error]

This is the error message I'm getting, I have no idea why. I've messed around with the preferences in java preferences on the mac, but on pc I have no problem running my application.

Comment: Have you tried clicking "Show Details..." to see what else it will tell you?

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch yeah, it shows the certificate it was signed with(mine), and allows you to trust it, however even after entering my password to trust the certificate, it still won't allow me to click allow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option on OS X Mountain Lion, that prevented anything not signed by a developer from running in the security tab of the system preferences, once the was changed, everything worked fine.